# Get User's friends user ID for app leaderboard scores

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

So, i'm creating a leaderboard where users can see global scores, regional scores and friends scores who have used the app before. all these scores are fetched and written to the fire store database in firebase along with the user's unique id when they log in with facebook.

I need to get a list of the users friends and their user ids from facebook so I can search the fire store database for their scores using the Facebook id. But I don't know how to get the id out of my result below when getting the list of friends:

```
func getFriendsFromFB() {

    let params = ["fields": "id, first_name, last_name, name, email, picture"]

    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/friends", parameters: params)
    let connection = FBSDKGraphRequestConnection()
    connection.add(graphRequest, completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let userData = result as? [String:Any] {
                print(userData)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error Getting Friends \(error)");
        }

    })

    connection.start()

}
```

**Can someone suggest how I get the user id out of my result in the code above?**

Also I do ask for the user_friends permission when asking the user to login.

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the result as a [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary), this means the results are stored as key values. You can retrieve values by using `dictionary["keyHere"]`. I'm not sure how the FB graph result is structured, but you will have to do something like this:

```
// Don't continue if the result is not a dictionary
guard let userData = result as? [String: Any] else {
    return
}

// Now, you can get values from the dictionary

// Let's say the userID is a String
if let userID = userData["id"] as? String {
    print(userID)
}
```